# Way to get Base64 from ImageURL in WSO2 ei

Tags: image-processing, base64, salesforce, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have imageURL like https://resource.digitaldealer.com.au/image/3281718625d81ce1e136a0008808648_0_0.jpg, my main aim is  **to push image into Salesforce**. For that, i'm trying **to get Base64 from this url**. once i get this base64 then i'll try to upload base64 content to Salesforce by using File concept of SFDC.

I have stuck while retrieve base64 from imageURL. Can anyone please help me?

FYI, **Code**

```
    <iterate continueParent="true" description="urlIterator" expression="//url" id="listUnread" sequential="true">
                    <target>
                        <sequence>
                            <property description="fileURL" expression="//*[local-name()='url']" name="fileURL" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
     <property description="uri.var.url" expression="get-property('fileURL')" name="uri.var.url" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                    <log separator="===Input Image URL===">
                                        <property expression="get-property('fileURL')" name="uri.var.url"/>
                                    </log>
                                    <call>
                                        <endpoint>
                                            <http method="get" uri-template="{uri.var.url}"/>
                                        </endpoint>
                                    </call> 
                                    <log level="full"/>
                   </sequence>
                </target>
      </iterate>
```

**Exception:**

```
[2019-12-09 12:26:14,762] [] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the %3Curl/%3E URL.
        at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:86)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:116)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [blog](http://ruwansrants.blogspot.com/2014/02/mediators-how-to-use-enrich-mediator-to.html) which explains **How to use Enrich Mediator to download an image from a URL and use Synapse functions to base64 encode same using WSO2 ESB**.

Comment: Hi @Pramodya ,
Thanks for your response.tried that one and working fine. once again thanks for your support